# PhpSpreadsheet - Download file instead of saving it

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I need to generate an excel file (xls) and trigger the download after it is generated.
I found this example in the [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

It shows how to create a excel file and save it on the server.
How can I serve the result to the client instead and "force" him to download it?
I need to get the data of the `$writer` somehow.

I am currently solving it without PhpSpreadsheet:

```
// Excel Export 
    $filename = 'export_'.date('d-m-y').'.xls';
    $filename = $validator->removeWhitespace($filename);

    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    exit($response["output"]);  // <-- contains excel file content
```

But it is not working with my delimiter (semicolon). The semicolon is not getting interpreted and everything is getting written into one column.

[image]

If I export it as .csv, then it works. But I need it as .xls or .xlsx

Comment: Hello, can you try that like in link: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/28#issuecomment-263101387

Comment: Does not work, it crashes at `$handle = $writer->save('php://memory');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it with a workaround. I temporarily save the file on the server, then I load the content into a variable and serve it as a download file. Then I delete the file from the server.

**Workaround:**

```
$date = date('d-m-y-'.substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8));
$date = str_replace(".", "", $date);
$filename = "export_".$date.".xlsx";

try {
    $writer = new Xlsx($response["spreadsheet"]);
    $writer->save($filename);
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);

unlink($filename);
exit($content);
```

Answer (score 55):

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class DownloadExcel
{
    public static function createExcel(array $data, array $headers = [],
                                       $fileName = 'data.xlsx')
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        for ($i = 0, $l = sizeof($headers); $i < $l; $i++) {
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i + 1, 1, $headers[$i]);
        }

        for ($i = 0, $l = sizeof($data); $i < $l; $i++) { // row $i
            $j = 0;
            foreach ($data[$i] as $k => $v) { // column $j
                $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($j + 1, ($i + 1 + 1), $v);
                $j++;
            }
        }

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. urlencode($fileName).'"');
        $writer->save('php://output');
    }

}
```

This is what I use to create a spreadsheet with PhpSpreadsheet and output directly to php://output for download.

Comment: Very good but if you have any output header sent earlier, the file downloaded will contain html data and excel will see it as a corrupted file, so you can add just in case `ob_clean();` before `$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);`.

Comment: I cant confirm right now if your method is working for me, because I currently work on another project. But I will definitely come back to this answer and then accept it if it works.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and found a solution here : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/217

I ended my method with `$writer->save('php://output');` then `exit()`

Answer (score 10):

My answer :
PHP:

```
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
ob_start();
$writer->save('php://output');
$ret['data'] = base64_encode(ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

JS:

```
var linkSource = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,'+ response.data ;
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
var fileName = 'clients.' + format;

downloadLink.href = linkSource;
downloadLink.download = fileName;
downloadLink.click();
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
$excel = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('This is a test', true);

ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="filename_' . time() . '.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$xlsxWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Xlsx');
$xlsxWriter = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($excel);
exit($xlsxWriter->save('php://output'));
```

Answer (score 3):

> call ob_end_clean(); just before the $writer->save('php://output').

```
ob_end_clean();
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems where the files download corrupted, it is always good to check if there is any extra whitespace at the top of your file output. If your PHP files have blank white lines, whilst HTML won't have a problem, your phpspreadsheet file will. Spent a good chunk of time trying to fix these issues but the problem was with the whitespace!

**Worth adding**

I am running one server with PHP 8.0.20 and others with 8.1/2. Recent updates to the ZIP dependencies use new 8.1/2 code and it doesn't work in 8.0. It may well therefore be your PHP version if recent (2023) updates fail to save.

Answer (score 0):

**I did it by using the simple CSV approach.**

*// column headers*

```
enter code here
$val = "REFERENCE,BdR,Arrivage,Model,NUMERO DE SERIE,Description,Dimension,Sur Quoi,Lieu \r";
```

*// the while loop of the data gathering function  note the \r at the end of the line.*

```
enter code here
while ($stmt->fetch()){     
    $item_arrival_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item_arrival_date));
    $val = $val . "$item_key,$arrival_rcpt_num,$item_arrival_date,$item_part_num,$item_serial_num,$item_descri,$size,$surface,$lieu \r";
    }
```

// Saving the CSV

```
enter code here
function save_as_csv($cust_num, $val){
if (file_exists('/volume1/...../inventory_excel/')){    

    $file_name = '/volume1/...../inventory_excel/'.$cust_num.'.csv';
 
    $myfile = fopen($file_name, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $val);
    fclose($myfile);
    }   
}
```