# TYPO3 v11.5 or newer - Get controller method to create XLSX, then send headers to download the file

Tags: excel, controller, header, typo3, xlsx

I cannot get this controller to create an XLS and download it. The code below does create the Excel. The Excel is also saved on the server, and I can see the file has the correct structure and content. However, the downloaded file contains the current page (HTML) code, not the stuff I am pulling from the Repository.

```php
public function exportAction()
{

    // Create a new PHPExcel spreadsheet
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    // Create a worksheet
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    // The Excel data logic goes here
    // (..)

    $tempFilePath = GeneralUtility::tempnam('export_', '.xlsx');
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save($tempFilePath);

    $uploadFolder = "fileadmin/";
    $uploadFolderAbsolutePath = GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($uploadFolder);

    $filename = "Upload.xls";
    $destinationPath = $uploadFolderAbsolutePath . "/" . $filename;

    GeneralUtility::upload_copy_move($tempFilePath, $destinationPath);

    unlink($tempFilePath);

    // The file upload.XLS is correct
    // The below does not work as expected.

    if (file_exists($destinationPath)) {
        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();

        $response = $response->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        $response = $response->withHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" . basename($filename));

        $response = $response->withHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

        $stream = new Stream($destinationPath, 'r');
        $response = $response->withBody($stream);

        return $response;

    }

    return $this->htmlResponse();

}
```

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971049/phpspreadsheet-download-file-instead-of-saving-it

Answer (score 0):

If the "workaround" of placing an exit helps, the reason may be that other actions are executed after your plugin and override the content, too.

You could then either adapt the following plugins, keep your workaround, or "resolve" your final action "properly" by throwing an immediate page resolve exception: https://api.typo3.org/9.5/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_http_1_1_immediate_response_exception.html

It sounds weird to throw an exception when that is the "proper" action, but it's "ok"

Answer (score 0):

"Adding the response interface as return for controller actions was a little bit early. The fact is, that the normal chain is discrupted and the response you create is not directly returned and used as the real request response.

Somewhere in the ContentObjectRendering and the dispatching to the extbase ecosystem the response object returned by the action is "dispanded" and returned as string in between. With this, repsonse header are lost.

It's possible to throw a specific exception which get's the response object attached, hard jumping to a later response point overjumping the normal content renter stack - and allows to return your build response along with all headers as it is.

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\PropagateResponseException;

public function exportAction()
{

    // Create a new PHPExcel spreadsheet
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    // Create a worksheet
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    // The Excel data logic goes here
    // (..)

    $tempFilePath = GeneralUtility::tempnam('export_', '.xlsx');
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save($tempFilePath);

    $uploadFolder = "fileadmin/";
    $uploadFolderAbsolutePath = GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($uploadFolder);

    $filename = "Upload.xls";
    $destinationPath = $uploadFolderAbsolutePath . "/" . $filename;

    GeneralUtility::upload_copy_move($tempFilePath, $destinationPath);

    unlink($tempFilePath);

    // The file upload.XLS is correct
    // The below does not work as expected.

    if (file_exists($destinationPath)) {
        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();

        $response = $response->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        $response = $response->withHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" . basename($filename));

        $response = $response->withHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

        $stream = new Stream($destinationPath, 'r');
        $response = $response->withBody($stream);

        // throw exception to jump over the content render stack
        // and use $response as is for the response.
        throw new PropagateResponseException($response);
    }

    return $this->htmlResponse();

}
```